# How to run 2 or more batch files in parallel, from an ant script?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, ant, cmd, parallel-processing

My intention is to run 2 batch files in parallel, using ant script.

Operating System: Windows 7

I tried this but doesnt work.

```
<project name="RBS" basedir=".">
    <!--<property name="buildC" value="${basedire}\build-C" /> -->
<target name="start batch parallely">
<parallel >
    <exec dir="RBS" executable="cmd" os="Windows 7">
        <arg line="/c run_parallel.bat"/>
    </exec>
   <exec dir="RBS\Retail_R6" executable="cmd" os="Windows 7">
        <arg line="/c RetailAutomation_R7.bat"/>
    </exec> 
</parallel>
</target>
</project>
```

Could someone help please ?

Answer (score 1):

"Note that .bat files cannot in general by executed directly. One normally needs to execute the command shell executable cmd using the /c switch." - https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

```
<exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="ant.bat"/>
    <arg value="-p"/>
  </exec>
```

Also `<exec></exec>` essentially wraps to windows `CreateProcess()` API which runs the bat or what ever file extension as it's own process which means it will run in parallel. Not positive but I believe your `<parallel></parallel>` only has the effect that it will start the .bats asynchronously.

Also I would follow up on msdn for the `CreateProcess()` API to ensure you are using `<exec></exec>` correctly for windows.

changed your code too

```
<project name="RBS" basedir=".">
    <!--<property name="buildC" value="${basedire}\build-C" /> -->
<target name="start batch parallely">
<parallel >
    <exec executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="RBS/run_parallel.bat"/> 
    </exec>
   <exec executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="RBS/Retail_R6/RetailAutomation_R7.bat"/> 
    </exec> 
</parallel>
</target>
</project>
```

Also the .bats have to be in the bottom of the working directory. If not change the second `<arg value>`'s to add the relative path before the file name. Maybe that should do it?